# Parsing file names using ruby Net::SSH

Tags: ruby, git, net-ssh

Working on automating a task for my job.

**Issue:** We have a rather large stack of git repos hosted on a private git server at our main office. I work at a remote location.

**Goal:** I need to clone many (50+) repos without authenticating and manually typing out the filename ever time.

This is supposed to be the quick and dirty version written in ruby (I'm currently learning ruby so I'm trying to use it for any and all needs it's good for) which I can use as a template for more fine tuned git operations in the future.

This is what I have right now:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'net/ssh'

git_server_address = "x.x.x.x"
git_server_login = "username"
puts "Enter password for #{git_server_login}"
git_server_passwd = gets.chomp
$gitnames = []


def getGitNames(address, login, passwd)
  Net::SSH.start(address, login, password: passwd) do |ssh|
    ssh.exec!("cd /git")
    ssh.exec!("find . -type d -exec echo '{}' \\;") do |file|
      $gitnames.push(file)
    end
  end
end

$gitnames = getGitNames(git_server_address, git_server_login, git_server_passwd)
$gitnames.each do |file|
  if file.equal?('slamros.git')
    puts(file)
    #puts system("git clone #{git_server_login}@#{git_server_address}:/git/#    {file}")
    #puts git_server_passwd
  end
end
```

If this is abhorrently ugly, I apologize, I'm still very new at my job and to professional programming. I know there are some best practices I'm not following but my goal was just to get this operational by EoD.

Essentially what I'm trying to do is use the `ssh.exec!` and `find -exec` to get the names of the files in the /git folder.

Once this is working I will use the filenames I have to pull git clones on my own system. I currently have these lines commented out.

My code currently asks for my password, processes for about 5 seconds, and then gives me this error:

```
/GitClone.rb:21:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
from -e:1:in `load'
from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

I get that what i'm doing in my getGitNames() method is wrong, but I would appreciate some help in pointing out what exactly it is or some ideas of other ways to accomplish my task with Ruby.